# Pass argument from ctest to gtest

Tags: cmake, googletest, ctest

I am using gtest to write unit tests for my application. I also have ctest that runs all executables added by add_test CMake command. Is it possible to pass gtest variables through ctest when test execution starts?

I would like to for example sometimes filter out tests with --gtest_filter flag but I don't know how or if this is even possible through ctest? I have tried the following ways:

```
ctest --gtest_filter=AppTest.*
ctest --test-arguments="--gtest_filter=AppTest.*"
```

But both still run all tests instead the filtered ones.

Thanks!

Comment: Those who also has this problem should perhaps upwote this Kitware request:  https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20470

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking here in 2019, recent versions of CMake have `gtest_discover_tests` (GoogleTest module) which will hoist your tests into CTest and you can filter from there.

IOW rather than having a single `add_test` in CTest, it will use `--gtest_list_tests` to call `add_test` for each of your tests.

Comment: Could you add an example of how to filter with `ctest`? `ctest -L FixtureName.*` did not work for me.

Comment: NVM seems like I should have used `-R` instead of `-L`.

Answer (score 2):

For example, to make tests' output verbose:

`$ make test ARGS="-V"`

To run a particular test:

`$ ctest -R <regex>`

**NB:** You can have a look at [this](https://github.com/mtavkhelidze/cmake-and-gtest-skeleton) for some examples.

Comment: This actually answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at CMakes's `add_test` [add_test](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/command/add_test.html).

To filter out tests from CTest you can use -L [ctest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.10/manual/ctest.1.html)

Comment: I know the params can be added to the add_test command but what I would like to achieve is to filter tests when running ctest - not by changing cmake files to achieve that.

Comment: And why is it not working to use `ctest -L <RegEx to match the tests I want>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a complex project with multiple test binaries (== multiple CMake `add_test` commands) each of which might have many different Google Tests, then an alternative option is to do:

```bash
env GTEST_FILTER="*some-keyword*" ctest -VV -R '.*some-test-type.*'
```

*some-keyword* will be passed to `--gtest_filter`

*some-test-type* will be used by CTest to filter which test binary (`add_test` command).

For example:

```bash
env GTEST_FILTER="*authentication*" ctest -VV -R '.*system.*'
```

...to run just the Authentication-related System tests. Any non-Authentication or non-System tests are skipped.